# How to fix an error deprecated error for sourceID

Tags: error-message, deprecation

In my CP I'm seeing an error that says:

`Elements’ getSourceId() method has been deprecated. Use getCanonicalId() instead.`

It references
`/storage/ad33d3/www/public_html/templates/jojojo/_sections/products/_partials/productDetails.twig:193`

When I look in that file I see this line:

`{entryId: entry.sourceId}) %}`

Is the fix as simple as changing that line to:

`{entryId: entry.canonicalId}) %}`

I'm relatively new to Craft/twig and this is a live site so I didn't want to just "test" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be all that’s required, but I’d highly recommend setting up a local development environment for this site so you don’t have to make changes to the live site and risk breaking it.

https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/environment/stack.html